# Identify the end of a long method in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Is there a way to identify the end of a method with xcode? For example in eclipse if you select a start of a method `{` it will highlight the end `}`. Is there something similar in xcode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on the start brace `{` or end brace `}` will move accordingly to the start to end / end to start. also it will select the code inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option in Xcode.

You can either:

- use folding to collapse/expand blocks of code delimited by `{}`
- use Xvim and use the `%` key to jump to the corresponding delimiter of the one your cursor is under, just like in vi.

Comment: Though I believe this was an option at some point in previous versions... correct me if I'm wrong.